# What happens when compiling against a shared library?

Tags: gcc, ld

I understand that when linking against a static library i.e. libname.a, the binary code for the used functions is taken out of the archive and *inserted* in the application binary. Therefore, the static library MUST be present at compilation time.

However, with shared libraries I am lost. The function definitions are not copied. Then **why is it needed that the shared library be provided on the linker command line**? Also, **are there different ways to link against shared libraries** and what are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shared libraries need to be fed to the linker's command line so that a reference to the specific functions and the file in which these functions reside, is stored into the executable. When the executable is run, the dynamic linker (`/lib/ld-linux.so`, `/libexec/ld-elf.so`, etc, depending on your system) is loaded first and checks these references. Once it finds the lib files, it maps them (using the `mmap()` system call) to your program's adress space.

You can see these references by running

```
objdump -T a.out
```

or

```
nm -D a.out
```

For ELF executables, the existence of the `.interp` section implies that the program uses dynamic linking.

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile, I found [this] (http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html)excellent tutorial, complementing your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

See the man pages for **dlopen** and **dlsym** for explicit dynamic link loader management.